# Cubic Spline Interpolation - Solve X from Y

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, cubics, spline

I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, but I've got a real-world problem I'm trying to solve that's out of my league, and my Google skills so far have failed me.

I have an analog waveform that's been sampled, part of which contains a sine wave, as shown below:
[image: Sampled data]
The sample rate of the data and the frequency of the sine wave are both constant, but unrelated. I need to take this sampled waveform, and "upsample" it, IE, generate more samples between the existing sample points. To do this, I've been using Cubic Spline Interpolation. I've taken an existing C++ library from the following location: http://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/opensource/spline/. The formulas are given on the page. I pass in the existing sampled data as control points, with "X" set to the sample number, and "Y" set to the sample value. Given an input value of X, this library generates me the corresponding "Y" value, so passing in an X of 2.5 would generate a value on the generated spline halfway between samples 2 and 3. All of this is working great so far, and it yields a waveform like the one shown above, but I now need to do one extra thing that I'm a bit stuck on.

What I need to be able to do now is "synchronize" with the the sine wave in the sample data. To do that, I want to detect the point at which the sine wave crosses a given threshold, as shown below:
[image: Threshold]
In other words, given a starting value of X, I want to calculate the next X value at which Y equals a given value. Currently I "brute force" an approximate solution, by incrementing by a given step size between two X values until I cross the threshold point. There are two problems with this:

1. Accuracy. The solution is only approximate, and I need a highly accurate result. This leads to a very small step size, while still having a margin of error.
2. Performance. I have literally billions of these operations to perform, and I want something that can evaluate in a reasonable period of time. Right now I have to trade off accuracy to improve performance.

Instead of using an imperfect brute force search like I currently do, I was wondering if there's a mathematical solution for this problem. I basically want a function that given an X start position and a target Y sample value, will return the next X where Y is equal to the target Y value. I believe this should be possible to achieve, but I lack the math skills to derive the formula myself. Can anyone tell me if such a function is theoretically possible to write, and if so, what a possible implementation would be?

Here are some potentially useful constraints on my input data, which any acceptable solution can assume:

- The X coordinates of control points are linearly increasing values (IE, all evenly spaced and never "doubling back")
- I know the upper and lower bounds for the X and Y coordinates of the control points when generating the spline

Please let me know if you can see a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you not use the cubic formula?

Comment: @law-of-fives Probably? I don't know, I'm new to this kind of analysis, and I need some hand-holding here. If you've got a possible answer, please post it with some explanation (IE, a formula and an example), and I'll give it a try.

Comment: Given an $x$ start position and a threshold value $y$ you can search forward until you find a pair of sample points $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$ that bracket the threshold value, i.e., $y_i \leq y < y_{i+1}$. You can then use the definition of the cubic polynomial $C_i(x)$ on the interval $I = [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ that you get from the cubic spline interpolation to solve for the point $x\in I$ such that $C_i(x) = y$. You could, for example, use a standard root finding method to solve for $x$.

Comment: Since the code you provided allows you to evaluate the spline at a point, you should be able to apply a root finding method to solve for $x$ once you have it bracketed. According to the code in spline.h, each time you evaluate the spline at a point, a binary search is done to find the interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ that contains the point. Since you will know ahead of time the interval in which to look, you could probably improve the lookup time to $O(1)$ by passing the index $i$. Of course, if the number of sample points is small, that may not be necessary.

Comment: Worrying about accuracy doesn't make much sense, to me. Your spline is already an approximation of the true wave-form, so trying to compute highly accurate answers from the spline is a dubious strategy.

Comment: I'd use an FFT to estimate the frequency of the sinusoid and then a little trigonometry to find the next points

Comment: I agree that generally this problem is conducive to Fourier analysis. If you window the function you could take a fast Fourier transform which would give you essentially a bunch of sinusoids fit to your function. If you assume it is one sinusoid as you are doing, just take the most prominent one and you can find the inverse of that very simply.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a polynomial root-finding problem.

You have a $y$-value, say $y = \bar{y}$, and you want to find $x$ such that $y(x) = \bar{y}$. In other words, you want to find a root of the function $f(x) = y(x) - \bar{y}$. The function $f$ is a cubic polynomial.

A few ideas:

(1) Go find a general-purpose root-finding function. Look in the "Numerical Recipes" book, for example. Brent's method seems to be a popular choice. You can just plug in your function $f$ directly, so less code to write than in the suggestions below.

(2) Go find some polynomial root-finding code. Again, there's some in the "Numerical Recipes" book. This may require you to find the polynomial coefficients of segments of your cubic spline, though. Not difficult, but it's work.

(3) There are formulas for finding the roots of cubic polynomials (see Wikipedia), but coding them correctly is surprisingly difficult. There's good code [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LowDegreePolynomialRoots.pdf) and [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Source/NumericalMethods.html). This will probably give you the best performance with cubics. Again, it will require you to find the polynomial coefficients of segments of your cubic spline.

(4) Switch to using quadratic splines instead of cubic ones. Then you only have to find roots of quadratic polynomials, not cubics, so the root-finding problem becomes trivial. This will be a pretty big change, but it will pay off if you need high performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the best way is for this problem so I hope someone comes along and gives you some magic whereupon I will happily delete this.

I have thought a little bit about the advantages a bisection search has but I have convinced myself, perhaps erroneously, that it is not going to outperform the cubic formula due to some tricky cases where the threshold is intersecting the same spline piece twice. Since this is a pretty plausible case I feel like the cubic formula will outperform a bisection search. If this is not true, a bisection search is going to be easier to write and probably cheaper on average than the cubic formula. [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) has the best convergence but I don't think it's really great in this case since you already lack a good estimate. However an initial bisection search followed by Newton-Raphson would be dynamite for convergence, but I think in the case of a cubic you're going to be performing very close to the same number of operations, so again I'm **guessing** the cubic formula will win. The cubic formula requires a lot of multiplications and some complex arithmetic so it's really not clear to me which is best, and from a numerical standpoint I definitely have no idea. I am posting this mostly because no one else has responded and maybe a little answer is better than nothing.

But, I'm not 100% clear if you have to find all the intersecting points, or just one intersecting point. If you only need to find one intersecting point for purposes of synchronizing, please use bisection and Newton's method. It's going to win.

If you want to give a shot at [the cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), you'll want to get your hands on the spline coefficients by modifying the library to make the coefficient vectors public and in the meantime get a solid complex number library if you don't already have it. You'll be taking the cube root of a negative number.

If your spline has coefficients $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + D$ and your threshold is at $y = Y$ then you want to find the zeros of $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where $d = D-Y$.

Calculate the discriminant $\Delta = 18abcd - 4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 -27a^2d^2$. You want this to know whether your cubic has one or three real roots. I guess it is theoretically possible you could get some floating point magic to have a double root ($\Delta = 0$).

Then use the form $x_k = -\frac{1}{3a}(b + \zeta^kC + \frac{\Delta_0}{\zeta^k C})$ for $k = 0,~ 1,~ 2$. Note wiki's comment about simplifying the calculation of $C$ since you calculated the discriminant.

So your formula gives you three roots, and your discriminant says you have

1. One real root. Look for the root in your set of three that fits the window you're currently looking in. Given the plots you have in your post I don't think there's going to be any edge cases here. Just find the right real part and discard the imaginary part as it's floating point error.
2. Three real roots.  It's possible your threshold crosses the spline at two points (like a cap or trough). The good news here is you can certainly discard all the imaginary parts as floating point error and just search for the real parts in your range.
3. A double root.

   a. The two roots which are very close in magnitude are in your range. This means your threshold is right on the tip of a peak or trough. I think there's absolutely no harm in ignoring this case.

   b. The two roots which are very close in magnitude, only one is in your range. You can probably ignore this case as well.

   c. The third root not close in magnitude is in your range. Well, you've got it, discard the imaginary part as floating point error.

Just in case this wasn't enough for you, I have to note that the library stores its coefficients in the form $a(x-x_i)^3 + b(x-x_i)^2 + c(x-x_i) + y_i$. So to know whether the root is "in range" you have to translate it by the window you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the general Cardano's formulas, which can be efficient when a floating-point coprocessor is available, you can try as follows:

- first check that the cubic has no extremum in the interval considered, let $[p,q]$; for this, locate the roots of $$3ax^2+2bx+c=0;$$

  - for this, check if the root of $6ax+2b=0$ lies in the interval, by comparing the signs of $3ap+b$ and $3aq+b$.
  - if true, split in the subintervals $[p,-\dfrac b{3a}]$ and $[-\dfrac b{3a},q]$;
  - evaluate the signs of $3ax^2+2bx+c$ at the endpoints of the relevant intervals (one or two). When you find a root of the quadratic, evaluate it and split the related interval.
- after this preliminary discussion, you will know from zero to three subintervals with exactly one root.
- finally, solve by a few iterations of the chord method or Newton's.

---

Another interesting approach (which can be implemented using integer arithmetic only) is to express the cubic polynomial as a cubic Bezier (there are simple formulas to translate from the canonical to Bezier forms). Then you can use

- the hull property to check if the curve crosses a given ordinate (the control points must be on either sides),
- the subdivision algorithm (known as De Casteljau’s) to find the control points of the left and right halves of the curves,
- recursion to the halves where crossings are detected.

You can organize the computation to perform only additions and comparisons, and the root finding process is of the dichotomic type. You can finish with linear interpolation.

---

As @bubba said, extreme accuracy is overkill as your interpolant is itself an approximation.